# Как считать запись из окна приложения?

Tags: python, winapi

Добрый день!

Есть окно приложения, как я могу получить список элементов интерфейса: слова, цифры?

Например такое окно:

[image]

Как мне получить данные: `System Properties`, `Computer Name`, `Hardware`, `Advanced`, и т.д.?

Есть ли в *Python* средства для работы с этими API?

Comment: получай из системы, зачем из этого окна пытаться выдрать?

Comment: ну в общем в этом и вопрос, как получать из системы?
И это окно- просто пример, мне не из него нужно будет вытаскивать записи.

Comment: Вы решили сдампить всю информацию с этого окна?

Comment: Да, но не с этого, но думаю, что принцип один и тот же.

Comment: от оси много зависит, судя по окошку надо курить в сторону Windows API

Answer (score 4):

Если речь не про систему, а просто за окна, то вам в сторону гугла со словами python gui automation. Это могут быть например autoit или pywingui.

Я лично люблю python+autoit.

**Autoit**

1. Установить AutoIt http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/
2. Установить pywin32

Написать что то такое:

```
import win32com.client
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")

autoit.Run("control.exe sysdm.cpl,,3") 
autoit.WinWait('System Properties')
autoit.WinActive('System Properties')

print autoit.ControlGetText('System Properties', "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
print autoit.ControlGetText('System Properties', "", "[CLASS:Static; INSTANCE:2]")
print autoit.ControlGetText('System Properties', "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
```

Табы кстати в таком autoit-е вроде без поллитры не обработать, но с простыми контролами все удобно. К тому же в в комплекте с autoit-ом поставляется инструмент для анализа окон - главным образом чтобы понять какой номер кнопки.

**PyWinAuto**

Другой вариант - pywinauto. Тут с табами все просто:

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.Start_("control.exe sysdm.cpl,,3")
app.connect_(title = "System Properties")
print app.SystemProperties.TabControl.Texts()
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466684/how-can-i-return-system-information-in-python) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467602/how-can-i-read-system-information-in-python-on-windows), смежных вопроса, на смежном проекте, ну и [гугл](http://bit.ly/18os5TX) в теме.

Там сотни инфы по теме, а в окна вам лезть не надо, они как и ваше ПО - средство визуализации этой информации, а вам хочется странного... вместо того, чтобы залезть в оф. источники информации.